# SPO missing EWA in Business Data

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-online, excel-services

Where trying to implement a EWA webpart to a teamsite, but we're missing EWA among other webparts available in the Business Data folder (see pic below)?

E3 license - check!
SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection feature is activated.
SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure is activated.
SharePoint Server Standard Site Collection features is activated.

We've run out of ideas

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Solved!
Make sure that no one changes permissions. :)